# sentence construction and verb form for: convenient for you that I do something

Tags: sentence-construction, subjunctives

Are any of the following correct?:

1.- Let me know when it's more convenient for you me going to your office.

2.- Let me know when it's more convenient me going to your office for you.

3.- Let me know when it's more convenient for you that I go to your office.

4.- Let me know when it would be more convenient for you that I should go to your office.

I think 4. is correct, but I would like to know so are any of the other possibilities (especially 1. or 2.). They seem less formal and might be more appropriate depending on the context.

PS: I have added the subjunctive tag because in Spanish that would be a present subjunctive form. If 3. is correct I will ask a separate question asking what happens if ''I'' is replace by ''he''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the sentences are quite awkward.

The first sentence can be made grammatical by replacing “me” with “my” in front of the gerund. It can be rendered less awkward by eliminating “for you” although that slightly alters the sense.

The second sentence has the same grammatical error with respect to “me” fronting the gerund. The placement of “for you” is even more awkward than in the first sentence.

The third and fourth sentences are both grammatical, but have different nuances. The third implies commitment whereas the fourth implies obligation. Based on sentences one and two, the third seems to express your intended meaning. (The subjunctive is a relic in modern English, and American usage with respect to it is in flux.)

So sentence one, with a slight correction, and sentence three are grammatical and express what I suspect is your intended meaning, but both are awkward. I would recast the sentence

> When would you find it more convenient for me to come to your office.

**EDIT**: I tried to stick as closely as possible to your sentences when discussing the sentences individually.

While I was writing my response, Kate Bunting posted her response. As you can see from my suggested alternative to your sentences, I agree with her that “come” is more idiomatic than “go” and that using an infinitive rather than a gerund leads to a far more natural structure of the sentence.

Comment: Sorry for the delay selecting the answer. I have chosen this one because it is the most detailed one, although the three are great answers. Thank you all for answering.

Answer (score 3):

As you are asking about their convenience, it's unnecessary to specify *for you*. As you will be going to their office, we would use *come* rather than *go* (looking at it from their point of view).

So, we would say

> Let me know when it would be convenient for me to come to your office.

Comment: Exactly. In a question, any unspecified emotions, preferences, or opinions are assumed to be those of the addressee; in a statement, they're those of the speaker.

Answer (score 1):

First point, subjunctive in Spanish is not important for the English.

Second point, you can leave out the *you* as it is implied:

- Let me know when it would be more convenient for me to go your office.
- Let me know when it is more convenient *for you for me* to go to your office.

That second one is correct though the *for you* is not necessary, really, in English. Also, *would be* or *is* can both work.